# How use text input as a dropdown button in bootstrap-vue?

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I want to make a select search box. When click on input the dropdown opens and can type on input  and filter it in dropdown.
I used Input as a dropdown button. But seems dropdown makes it read-only.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
  return {
  form: {
      email: ''
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" text="Dropdown Button" class="m-md-2">
    <template #button-content>
      <b-form-group
          id="input-group-1"
          label="Email address:"
          label-for="input-1"
          description="We'll never share your email with anyone else."
        >
          <b-form-input
            id="input-1"
            v-model="form.email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            required
          ></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>
    </template>
    <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
    <b-dropdown-item active>Active action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item disabled>Disabled action</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest using `vue-multiselect` for your work, whereas I'll try to solve your problem with `b-vue`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the @click.stop on input event and setting the input focus.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        email: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    inputFocus() {
      this.$refs.emailInput.focus()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" text="Dropdown Button" class="m-md-2">
    <template #button-content>
      <b-form-group
          id="input-group-1"
          label="Email address:"
          label-for="input-1"
          description="We'll never share your email with anyone else."
        >
          <b-form-input
            id="input-1"
            v-model="form.email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            required
            @click.stop="inputFocus"
            ref="emailInput"
          ></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>
    </template>
    <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
    <b-dropdown-item active>Active action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item disabled>Disabled action</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```